# Template seems to wait for Observable to yield only once

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I'm pulling an array using a service and the template is using it to populate a list using `*ngFor`.

It's working fine for the first list, but I have a second list that uses a subset of the array and it yields the following error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

**component.ts :**

```
export class AudioVideoComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: Category[];
  subCategories: SubCategory[];

  constructor(private musicService: MusicService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = [];
    this.getAudioVideoCategories();
  }


  getAudioVideoCategories(): void {
    this.musicService.getAudioVideoCategories().subscribe(categories => {
      this.categories = categories;
      this.subCategories = flatten(categories.map(cat => cat.subCategories));
      console.log(this.subCategories);
    });
  }
}
```

**component.html :**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs firstNavBox">
    <li *ngFor="let category of categories"><a>{{category.label}}</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs secondNavBox">
    <li *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories"><a>{{category.label}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if I add an Elvis operator to the second list : `{{category?.label}}` I have no error but the list isn't populated.

Any idea how to get the template to wait for `subCategories` to be populated before trying to populate the second list ?

Comment: try using a null safety operator on your category label like this `{{category?.label}}`

Comment: also why are you using `{{category.label}}` in the second loop instead of `{{subCategory.label}}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this a copy-paste error?

Is:

```
<li *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories"><a>{{category.label}}</a></li>
```

Shall be:

```
<li *ngFor="let subCategory of subCategories"><a>{{subCategory.label}}</a></li>
```

Your template parser complains, because you are referring to `category` variable which is not existing in scope of second `*ngFor`

Comment: Told by person that mastered `R` language ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `{{subCategory.label}}` in the second ngFor.